# Firebase Firestore Securitty Rule | Allow read if field value same as auth uid

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I want to read all document from

[image]

using this query

```
QuerySnapshot data = await firestore
          .collection('Order')
          .where('uId', isEqualTo: auth.currentUser!.uid)
          .limit(20)
          .get();
```

and also want to apply security **read** only the requested auth uid same as uId/sellerUId.

I already try with this security rule

```
    match /Order/{uniqueCode} {
        allow read: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/Order/$(uniqueCode)).data.sellerUId == request.auth.uid ||
                    get(/databases/$(database)/documents/Order/$(uniqueCode)).data.uId == request.auth.uid;
      allow write, update, delete: if true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to specify the complete path if the fields you want to compare with are already in document.

```
match /Order/{uniqueCode} {
      allow read: if resource.data.sellerUId == request.auth.uid || resource.data.uId == request.auth.uid;
      allow write, update, delete: if true;
}
```

You can read more about data validation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#data_validation)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is causing your problem, but you probably don't want to `get()` the same document that you're securing. Instead you can use `resource` to refer to it:

```
match /Order/{uniqueCode} {
    allow read: if resource.data.sellerUId == request.auth.uid ||
                   resource.data.uId == request.auth.uid;
    allow write, update, delete: if true;
}
```